# Flutter app debugging failed, dart:html missed

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-debugging

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Invalid depfile: G:\name\flutter_projects\flutter_application_1.dart_tool\flutter_build\f1291c0d140e6f8c93f6f49b9ff6a808\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: G:\name\flutter_projects\flutter_application_1.dart_tool\flutter_build\f1291c0d140e6f8c93f6f49b9ff6a808\kernel_snapshot.d
: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:652:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:792:21)

#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:615:9)

#4      starter (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1433:12)

#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

When i try launching debug with VS Code emulator everything goes same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that work for me is: Delete your `pubspec.lock`, and press 'Pub Get' in your `pubspec.yaml`, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.

Comment: Think you! I also deleted file kernel_snapshot.d, and this start to work well!

Comment: Glad to help you.